# Simulating stochastic differential equation with jumps.

Tags: numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, simulation

I've got equation like this:
$$dX(t) = \alpha (t,X) dt + \sigma (t, X) dW(t) + \int_{Z} \gamma (z) X(t^{-})\tilde{N}(dt,dz)$$

I know how to simulate equations like: $$dX(t) = \alpha (t,X) dt + \sigma (t, X) dW(t) + \beta(t,X)dN(t),$$ but how to do it when we have got this integral with respect to Poisson measure?

Comment: Can you post links to papers or publications that reference the construction of the first SDE?

Comment: My particular example is from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965913000955 .

Theory and construction you can find for example in Applebaum https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/levy-processes-and-stochastic-calculus/4AC698D37D3D8E57D099B73ADF4ACB11

Comment: You may request the paper's code from the authors.

Comment: That's what I did :)